# Multiple application deployment for WebSphere

Tags: deployment, websphere, web-deployment

I want to ask a general question that I guess, people who are using WebSphere App Server have thought.

Can we deploy multiple EAR or WAR files **at once** by using a **Jython** script but only use one sync node and save command?

I have some concerns about boundaries like EAR file size and number of EARs but I have found nothing on it online yet.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can install/update multiple applications and then Save/Sync Node at once by using a wsadmin script like the following:

```
AdminApp.install(fullapppath1,params1) 
AdminApp.install(fullapppath2,params2)
AdminConfig.save()
AdminNodeManagement.syncActiveNodes()
```

In fact this can have some performance benefits in contrast with save/sync operation for each app.

Regarding EAR max file size I do not know whether there are any WAS-relative limits except two issues:

- Really Big EAR/WAR files can severelly slow down the deployment process
- Watch for your OS *max Number of files per process* limits (i.e. `nofile` parameter in Linux). This can prevent the EAR expansion process in case you have many jars in your app.

Comment: Hi trikelef, firstly thanks for your very fast answer. When I said the multiple , I mean for example 20-30 EAR files. Can this structure of script be available in that case ?

Comment: Yes you can write a for loop over the ear list with AdminApp.install operations

Comment: Hi, just a simple ques: Do running multiple war/ear on WAS will run under single JVM only and use the same heap memory assigned for WAS ?  Also, is it possible to control single application heap usage by setting the maximum? Also, I see we are able to start stop and restart a single app, hiw is it possible under single JVM?